# Laravel Dusk feature tests - getting 403 errors

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have a test file in the tests/Feature directory with the following contents:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testA()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs(\App\AdminUser::find(1))
            ->json('GET', '/users');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function testB()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs(\App\AdminUser::find(1))
            ->json('GET', '/users');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when both tests are executed the assertion in the second one fails with the following error: `Expected status code 200 but received 403.` - Laravel throws an `AccessDeniedHttpException` for some reason.

If I comment out either test method the other one works.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

--- Edit ---

Here's what's in the controller method:

```
public function index() {
    return view('users.index');
}
```

And the definition in the routes file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users', 'as' => 'users.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
    Route::get('datatables', ['as' => 'datatables', 'uses' => 'UserController@datatables']);
    Route::get('show/{id}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
});
```

--- Edit 2 ---
Turns out this is an issue with the package I'm using. Further info: https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/issues/306

Comment: Post your middleware code. This is wierd though

Comment: I'm using the Bouncer package (https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer), however, commenting out the relevant bits and leaving the default 'auth' middleware in place results in the same result.

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint at the second `$assert` and have a look at the actually logged in user. 
Please show us the controller code which is executed when you hit `/users`.

Comment: The user does exist before the second `assert` - the table record is returned.
Please see the updated post for the controller method and route definitions.